# Extract Gstreamer alsa microphone data and send packets through UDP using my own Network solution for transport

Tags: c, linux, networking, gstreamer, microphone

I'm trying to figure out how I can send streaming audio data through my own UDP packeting system, I realise there is an ultra convenient functions built into Gstreamer but I truly believe i must do this manually in order for my project to work.

So even though I've successfully written my own TCP stream and UDP stream, I basically just need to know how I can take a Gstreamer pipeline and convert it to tiny frames for me to process manually and send through the UDP packets(or stream how ever you view this ideology). I doub't its as simple as just putting the Gstreamer pipeline into the UDP packet sending request every time right?

The source is an audio input (or so I presume)

The following code dosen't show the UDP networking stream, however it does provide a ground for someone to show me how I can utilize the current setup to convert into some kind of usable bytestream/binarystream for UDP packets.

```
#include "gst/gst.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("alsasrc device=hw 0", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

EDITS:
I mainly want to use my own encryption methods (RSA 3096 BITS of entropy) or use stronger ones I don't like the built in encryption methods for what is built into the current systems.

Comment: More research tells me I need to use GIO as that looks like PCM data but not sure how to use it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

My researching is telling me that Gstreamer is mostly for applications that need on the fly encoding/decoding and although recording would be supported it sounds like I need raw data to handle so I'll need a direct library like PortAudio instead.

Comment: You can embed your audio into a mpeg-ts stream, and transfer that using udp. But I am not sure if uncompressed audio is supported. If you are able to write it to a file, then you can also send it using udp, both multicast as unicast.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these [examples](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp). You can realize this fully inside gstreamer without that your application needs to do the network side of things even.